# How can I match values from different dataframes based on some conditions or function using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, match, conditional-statements

Suppose I have two dataframes as below.

```
raw_data = {
    'name': ['Jason love you', 'Molly hope wish care', 'happy birthday', 'dog cat', 'tiger legend bird'],
    'nationality': ['USA', 'USA', 'France', 'UK', 'UK']
}

raw_data_2 = {
    'name_2': ['Jason you', 'Molly care wist', 'hapy birthday', 'dog', 'tiger bird'],
    'nationality': ['USA', 'USA', 'France', 'UK', 'JK'],
    'code': ['a', 'b','c','d','e']
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['name', 'nationality'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data_2, columns = ['name_2', 'nationality', 'code'])
```

What I want to do is matching two dataframes based on some conditions.
The condition here is that

1. if there exists a name from `raw_data_2` which is a subset of a value (name) from `raw_data_1` when these two names are split by space, and
2. the nationality should be same.

For easier understanding here's an example: from `raw_data_2`, `'Jason You'.split(' ') = ['Jason', 'You']`, so this is a subset of `'Jason Love You'.split(' ') = ['Jason', 'Love', 'You']`.
But `'Molly care wist'.split(' ')` is NOT a subset of `'Molly care wish'.split(' ')` because the latter does not cover the former entirely (perfectly).
`'tiger bird'.split(' ')` from `raw_data_2` is a subset of `'tiger legend bird'.split(' ')`, but their nationality is different.

If we meet the above conditions, then finally I want to assign the `code` value from `raw_data_2`.
So the desired output(let's just take the `code`s) would be like:

```
'a'(matched), Nan(unmatched), Nan(unmatched), 'd', Nan(unmatched)
```

How can I do this by using pandas? I guess this is not just as simple as 'isin' function or 'map' function.

Comment: Does the letter case play any role?

Comment: in this case I don't want to classify lower / uppercase. Let's just ignore'em.

Comment: Are you comparing row by row?  Or all possible combinations?

Comment: not row-by-row. the example above seems to be not proper. I meant to 'search for all cases'. for example, the first row 'Jason love you' has to consider every rows from the df2. Simply, it means that only comparing row_1 and row_2 is wrong. For each row in df1, we have to 'find' for a value from df2 that matches the condition(subset and nationality).

Answer (score 1):

***Using `<=` operator to test for subset***

```
name = df1.name.str.split().apply(set)
name2 = df2.name_2.str.split().apply(set)
cond1 = name2 <= name
cond2 = df1.nationality == df2.nationality

pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, keys=['df1', 'df2']).loc[cond1 & cond2]

              df1                    df2                 
             name nationality     name_2 nationality code
0  Jason love you         USA  Jason you         USA    a
3         dog cat          UK        dog          UK    d
```

Comment: In fact, my example seems to be a little bit wrong. The df1 is far larger(longer) than df2, so the two dataframes have to be different length.  And the current example was so easy to compare by row-to-row(every row is similar each other), but it actually has to be in different order. It will be somewhat complex than before.

Comment: My question seems to be a bit vague.. My purposse was to match values(in this case it is subset condition) based on a dictionary(df2). So if there is a large dataset(df1), I wanted to match all names which can be a subset of some value from the dictionary. So it is natural that the order and length of the both dataframes will not be equal(it can be equal, but normally this is not general.).